# IPv6 DNS Server when there is none

Tags: windows-7, dns, ipv6

I have a Windows 7 Laptop I connect into remotely from another laptop and started having problems doing so with the hostname.  This was a problem when remote and not knowing the IP address.  NSLOOKUP showed the hostname had an IP address on our VPN tunnel.  This laptop was last connected this way over 3 months ago.

After investigating, I found there is a IPv6 DNS server set by DHCP with a link-local address.  My site does not have IPv6 enabled.  I could not detect this device and so converted to its MAC address and reported to my IT department.  He scanned the whole network and this device does not exist.

When at home, I checked with a different laptop and could see this DNS Server was my home router.  So, why is my laptop maintaining this DNS Server when it is not present on the connected network?

Key Facts:

- Windows 7 Laptop last connected to home network with IPv6 Enabled over 3 months ago.
- Laptop has had multiple reboots.
- Turning IPv6 off and on on the interface removed the DNS Server.
- Disconnecting and re-connecting to work network restores this DNS Server.